# Where created contract address come from?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, ganache

when i creat smart contract
i found to address in ganache
first sender address,the address which deploy the contract in remix
second the created contract address, where come from , what diffirent between two address
and How to add balance two address[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sender address is 1 of (default)10 testing accounts generated by Ganach. These accounts are setup with a default balance of 100 ether.

The contract address is generated at deployment using a combination of deployer's address & nonce.
To get a balance to the contract you'd create a transaction sending eth from one of the sender accounts to the contract